# Take total price from all product for many users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, eager-loading

i have issue

Model Driver has association like `has_many: orders`

```
class Driver < User
   has_many :orders
end
```

and Order has `belongs_to :user`

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

and `Order` has column like `price`

My problem is, i want to display all drivers by table
first column will be first_name, next last_name,
i want to display total price for each users. price will be counting by summing by all orders for user,
Problem is n+1, how i can display total price for each user, without sent separate request to the DB

Example of index page

| first_name. | last_name | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arian | Lain | 2500 |
| Brain | Kokun | 4700 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a sum for grouped values using a single SQL query with `SUM` and `GROUP BY`. In Rails, this can look like this:

```
@sums = Order.group_by(:user_id).sum(:price)
# {1 => 2500, 2 => 4700, ...}
```

In your view, you can then fetch the sum for the respective user using the user's id as a key, e.g. with this (assuming you have the current driver / user in the `driver` variable):

```
<%= @sums[driver.id] %>
```

Comment: won't this be a problems when the number of records in the database increases to 1 million or more?

Comment: Well, you can always filter the users you want to fetch with an appropriate `where` clause to only those users you want to display. Usually, you will have some kind of pagination or filtering.